# Enabling mcrypt, soap and pdo_mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos, mcrypt

I am having some issues with enabling the modules mentioned in the title on my CentOS machine.

yum install php-mcrypt / php-soap / php-mysql worked fine and mentioned that they had been installed, after restarting Apache it appears that they aren't enabled.

I cannot locate the mcrypt.so for example, and running php --ini gives:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './mcrypt.so' - ./mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

This is after I put extension=mcrypt.so in the php.ini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing extension_dir = "" to extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 8 (hardy), the mcrypt library seems to be here.

```
   /usr/lib/php5/20060613/mcrypt.so
```

in php.ini

change this text :

```
 ;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it was due to the default modules directory being unset.

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini you just have to remove semi column before mcypt.dll. Look for mcypt.dll and remove semi column before that

change this text :
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
to
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
(ie. remove ; )

Comment: This was attempted but I have found the reason for the error.